BOLT12: is there a way to store a detailed itemized receipt in any field?
When using BOLT12 offers in a point of sale application, is there any way to embed the entire detailed itemized receipt into the offer and invoice?
For example

4L of milk (400 sat)
2kg ground beef (600 sat)
1kg sugar (300 sat)
(1) tube toothpaste (150 sat)
(4) rolls toilet paper (250 sat)
etc.

Can we store this much data in offers and invoices and if so, what field?
Possibly we don't want to store this data in an offer because the offer should be short so it can be encoded in a small QR code, but is there any reason to keep it out of the invoice if that is sent through onion messaging? Is there any limit to how much data we can relay through onion messaging (seems like there is not an incentive based approach to onion messaging in lightning, so I'm not sure how nodes decide to relay messages for free)?
